# I'm wondering if this MySQL query is correct? (MySQL joining fun!)

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join, relational-database

I am wondering if this query is correct.  I am trying to SELECT the people (name/email) whose most recent log entry (or NULL if the person never logged for that event) per event per person that was posted LESS THAN n days ago.  Here are the table constraints:

- An event has a unique ID, but can have multiple log entries for it.
- An event can have multiple staff members on it.
- A staff member can be assigned to multiple events.
- A staff member will only log to events which he/she is a part of.
- If a staff member is part of an event, a "0" will be in the date_dropped_event field.  If the staff member quits the event this will change to a non-zero timestamp.  If the staff member later rejoins the event a new row will be created with a "0" timestamp.

I am using the following query:

```
SELECT
     max(`log`.`date_added`) AS `logdate`,
     `log`.`description`,
     `eventppl`.`staff_id`,     

     `staff`.`name`,
     `staff`.`email`,

     `event`.`name`,
     `event`.`deleted`

FROM `events` AS `event`
     LEFT JOIN `logs` AS `log` ON `log`.`event_id` = `event`.`event_id`
     LEFT JOIN `events_people` AS `eventppl` ON `event`.`event_id` = `eventppl`.`event_id`
     LEFT JOIN `staff` AS `staff` ON `eventppl`.`staff_id` = `staff`.`staff_id`
WHERE 
    `event`.`deleted` = 0 AND
    `eventppl`.`date_left_event` = 0 AND
    DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`log`.`date_added`)) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
GROUP BY `event`.`name`
```

I have the following table structures:

**logs**

```
  log_id   |   main_event_id  |  description        |  date            | staff_id
     1                    1          log entry         timestamp           11199
     2                    1          log entry         timestamp           11199
     3                    1          log entry         timestamp           11127
     4                    2          log entry         timestamp           11199
     5                    2          log entry         timestamp           11199
```

**events**

```
  event_id  |      name     |   deleted
    1          EVENT_name1       0
    2          Event_name2       0
    3          Event_name3       1
```

**events_people (11199) later rejoined**

```
event_id  |  staff_id    | date_left_event
   1          11199              234234234
   1          11126                 0
   1          11125                 0
   1          11199                 0
   2          11199                 0
   3          11199                 0
```

**staff**

```
staff_id    |    name    |   email
  11125         john         a@b.com
  11126         jane         a@bbasfd.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `where` clause is undoing the `left outer join`s.  When there is no match, the values in the columns of the second table are `NULL`, which automatically fail comparisons.

The solution is to move the comparisons from `where` to `on`:

```
FROM `events` AS `event`
     LEFT JOIN `logs` AS `log`
     ON `log`.`event_id` = `event`.`event_id` and
        DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(`log`.`date_added`)) <= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
     LEFT JOIN `events_people` AS `eventppl`
     ON `event`.`event_id` = `eventppl`.`event_id` and `eventppl`.`date_left_event` = 0
     LEFT JOIN `staff` AS `staff` ON `eventppl`.`staff_id` = `staff`.`staff_id`
WHERE `event`.`deleted` = 0 
GROUP BY `event`.`name`
```

Comment: That seems to be pulling a lot of NULL entries and things that are incorrect.  When I try to restrict to a known staff ID to make the results more manageable your query gives me the incorrect results, mine works (but im not sure if it works for all cases).  To filter I followed your pattern and did:  " LEFT JOIN `events_people` AS `eventppl`
     ON `event`.`event_id` = `eventppl`.`event_id` and `eventppl`.`date_left_event` = 0 AND `eventppl`.`staff_id` = KNOWN_STAFF_ID"